# Android Studio not recognizing Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

In build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

In my code:

```
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
```

I don't think this was an issue before, but all of the sudden today it's saying "cannot resolve symbol" for all of the import statements and so lots of things in my code are now wrongly marked as errors, even though when I run my app it works fine. What could be causing this?

Comment: bcz i m sure that you upgrade your facebook dependency. your imports are useless in newer version.. i also face the same problem.. just downgrade or try to implement new code from facebook getting started.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

tools>android>sync project files with gradle files

Comment: In Android 3.5, it's File-Sync Project with Gradle Files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S->selectApp->Dependandies->select"+"->moduledependandies->choose facebooksdk